# Many repeating syntax errors with no visible errors

Tags: ruby

```
puts("This program is intended to tell you your letter grade, and if you passed or")
puts("failed.")
puts
print("What was your grade for the class you are testing for?: ")
grade = Integer(gets)
puts
print("What was the name of the class?: ")
class = gets
class = class.chomp
puts
if grade >= 90
    puts
    puts("You passed!")
    puts
    puts("Your letter grade for " + class + " is an A!")
elsif grade >= 80
    puts
    puts("You Passed")
    puts
    puts("Your letter grade for " + class + " is a B.")
elsif grade >= 70
    puts
    puts("You Passed")
    puts
    puts("Your letter grade for " + class + " is a C.")
elsif grade >= 60
    puts
    puts("You Failed...")
    puts
    puts("Your letter grade for " + class + " is a D.")
elsif grade < 60
    puts
    puts("You Failed...")
    puts
    puts("Your letter grade for " + class + " is a F...")
else
    puts
    puts("It is not possible to get a negative grade. Please try again.")   
end
```

This is intended to take the users input, tell the user if they passed or failed, and their letter grade.

The errors mainly say "syntax error, unexpected unary+", "=" or ")"

Comment: Can you paste in the actual error messages?

Comment: `class` is a [keyword](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/), therefore not a good variable name.

Comment: Clarifying @Blorgbeard 's comment, it's not that `class` is not a _good_ variable name, it's that it's a reserved word, and so is an _invalid_ variable name. `class` marks the beginning of a class definition, which has a specific syntax; trying to use it as a variable name is a syntax error.

Comment: When you are asking about what error messages mean, you should really paste in the actual error messages. The exact message, stack trace, line numbers, etc. will be helpful to those trying to help you.

Comment: Unfortunately I happen to be using the ruby command prompt, so I can't copy and paste any of the errors. However, I found a solution anyways. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Well first of all change the name of the `class` variable to something a little different like `class_name` to prevent weird things happening later is you want to use it for more things.

A unary expresion can only use [one operand.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unary_operation) The "unary error" is most likely due to the way you're giving the string argument to the `puts` function using the `+` sign to separate operands, try saving the string in a variable and then passing it to puts as the argument.

Example:

`grade_a_announcement = "Your letter grade for " + class + " is an A!"`
`puts(grade_a_announcement)`

Furhtermore, as a recommendation for a program where you have to check against a variable in multiple occasions use`case` instead of all those `if`'s as seen [here in the "Ruby case Statement" section.](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_if_else.htm)

Answer (score 0):

The "unary operator" errors are, as @Dimovict said, because of how you wrote your `puts` call. The more idiomatic way to get the effect you want, though, is to use string interpolation:

```
puts("Your letter grade for #{class} is an A!")
```

This inserts `class` where `#{class}` is located in the string, and should remove the errors you're getting (unless you have more in code you haven't shown).